# How to write a factory function in swift?

Tags: swift2

There are a number of other questions floating around with various complicated answers for this question, but as far as I can see, none of them answer the *basic question* being posed:

How do you write a factory function that takes a *type* and returns an *instance* when the return type is known?

That is:

```
func factory<T>(T) -> Fooish { ... }

// Usage:
class Something : Fooish { ... }
let x:Fooish = factory(Something)
```

For example, this code:

```
public class Fooish {
  var x:String = ""
  public func foo() -> String {
    return x
  }
}

public class FooA : Fooish {
  public override init() {
    super.init()
    x = "Hello"
  }
}

public class FooB : Fooish {
  public override init() {
    super.init()
    x = "World"
  }
}

// This works
print(FooA().foo())
print(FooB().foo())

// This does not work
func factory<U>(type:U) -> Fooish {
  return U()
}

print(factory(FooA).foo())
print(factory(FooB).foo())
```

Results in this error:

```
Sources/main.swift:32:10: error: 'U' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
  return U()
     ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
```

So what *is* the bound to place on `T`, such that we can call `T()` and know that the returned instance is a some `Fooish`?

Some answers suggest using a protocol for it, such as:

```
protocol IsFoo {
  init()
}

factory<T: IsFoo>(t:T) -> Fooish { .. }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
error: cannot invoke 'factory' with an argument list of type '((FooA).Type)'
expected an argument list of type '(U)'
```

Every answer to this question seems to have multiple conflicting and updated answers; please, just simply post the snippet above, with a working implementation of the function `factory`, for swift 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a protocol which defines a common initializer to be called by the factory method:

```
protocol FactoryInitializable {
    init ()
}

func factory<T: FactoryInitializable>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    return T()
}

public class Fooish {
  var x = ""
  public func foo() -> String {
    return x
  }
}

public class FooA : Fooish, FactoryInitializable {
  required public override init() {
    super.init()
    x = "This is FooA"
  }
}

public class FooB : Fooish, FactoryInitializable {
  required public override init() {
    super.init()
    x = "This is FooB"
  }
}

let a = factory(FooA)
let b = factory(FooB)

print(a.x) // print: This is FooA
print(b.x) // print: This is FooB
```